# SQL Server : Request for extracting the strings following each occurence of same substrings

Tags: sql-server, split, substring, charindex, patindex

I have a string with this format

```
"AB=10,AC=11,AC=12,AC=13,AD=14,AD=15,AD=16"
```

and I would like to put the numbers in different columns, giving to each column the name you can find in the string before the `=`associated with this number.

So here, I would like to have 7 columns like that

| AB | AC1 | AC2 | AC3 | AD1 | AD2 | AD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

Edit: This structure is fixed, and we'll always have one AB, three AC, and three AD.

My problem is that we have 3 occurrences of `AC` and 3 occurrences of `AD`, and I can't reach data contained in the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of `AC` and `AD`. I tried with `PATINDEX` and `CHARINDEX` and always reach only the first occurrence.

Is it possible to do it in a single `SELECT` query?

Comment: are these columns fixed or dynamic?  For example if there was an additional AB=9 ... would there be columns AB1 and AB2 ?

Comment: SQL Server has recently introduced [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zorov,  it's SQL Server 2016 Management Studio (v 13.0.16106.4)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Good question, I forgot to mention it and will edit the question: this structure is fixed, always one AB, three AC and three AD

Comment: @Alex Yes I know, I'm just trying to do it in a single request without using variables. Is is possible with STRING_SPLIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a JSON-based approach. You need to transform the input into a valid JSON with the appropriate structure (`'AB=10,AC=11,AC=12,AC=13,AD=14,AD=15,AD=16` into `[{"AB":10},{"AC":11},{"AC":12},{"AC":13},{"AD":14},{"AD":15},{"AD":16}`) and parse it with `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(max) = N'AB=10,AC=11,AC=12,AC=13,AD=14,AD=15,AD=16'
SET @input = CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(@input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]')

SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[0].AB') AS AB,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[1].AC') AS AC1,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[2].AC') AS AC2,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[3].AC') AS AC3,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[4].AD') AS AD1,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[5].AD') AS AD2,
   JSON_VALUE(@input, '$[6].AD') AS AD3
```

Result:

```
AB  AC1 AC2 AC3 AD1 AD2 AD3
10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

If the data is stored in a table:

```
SELECT 
   t.Input,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[0].AB') AS AB,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[1].AC') AS AC1,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[2].AC') AS AC2,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[3].AC') AS AC3,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[4].AD') AS AD1,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[5].AD') AS AD2,
   JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Input, ',', '"},{"'), '=', '":"'), '"}]'), '$[6].AD') AS AD3
-- change the FROM clause with the real table and column names
FROM (VALUES (N'AB=10,AC=11,AC=12,AC=13,AD=14,AD=15,AD=16')) t (Input)
```

Comment: That's working really well!!! Thanks a lot! Just have to see if I can declare variables for my requests, because I'll use that on SSIS. But it should be great

Comment: Is this working if I need to get the original string from a table? I mean here you declare a variable and assign the string, but initially, I take this string from a column of the table and one to create 7 new columns based on the values of this column (strings with this format)

Comment: Your second answer is amazing! I'm really sorry to ask that, but how do you do this replacemenet with the table and the column. I do: SELECT MytableAlias.MyField, JSON..., JSON,....JSON, (replacing t.input by MytableAlias.MyField)... FROM MyTable as MyTableAlias. And it says : JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 's' is found at position 7 ... Do you see the problem?

Comment: Maybe my format problem is due to the fact that in my real srtrings, we don't have numbers (i just wanted to make a clear example) but strings ( little sentences in english), and maybe your format was done for numbers, right?

Comment: @Jonathan You are right. The answer assumes, that the values are numbers. Please, check the updated answer, but note that if the sentence contains JSON special characters, you'll need to escape them with `STRING_AGG()`. If you have problems, please post test data. Thanks..

Comment: You don't even know how much you helped me. It's working nicely. I just have maybe one last question.  I know I said it was never dynamic, but I just found in some records that it could be, mean we can have more than 3 AC and 3 AD, for instance one AB, four AC, and five AD (the maximum I could find is 6 AD. I guess it's a completely different problem. Or is it a small change? With a loop?

Comment: @Jonathan A dynamic statement is an option here, but yes, it's probably a good reason for another question.

Comment: You're right, and I asked another related question with this dynamic problem but in a more simple way than what I asked just above (I don't need such a complex thing). You're answer here helped me a lot. And the subsidiary question is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734282/sql-server-how-to-find-the-substring-just-after-the-last-occurence-of-another-s :) Don't think it's too long to answer, if you could it would be so nice