# SQL Server: how to find the substring just after the last occurence of another substring and before the next comma

Tags: sql-server, request, substring

I have a table in a SQL Server database which has a column `ColumnStrings` with strings of this kind:

```
"AB=ikkw0116,AC=BE D Work stations,AC=BE D stations,AC=D Allocated,AD=pnser,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased"
"AB=ikkWA001S1,AC=BE D HD,AC=D Allocated,AD=pnser,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased"
"AB=iksw0084,AC=Domain View,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased"
"AB=GHRS05900263,AC=Big stations,AC=GHR,AC=BE,AD=ger,AD=eu,AD=intra"
```

So we have a random number of `AB=`, `AC=` and `AD=`.

I would like to get the value (substring placed after the equal sign and before the next coma) just after the last occurrence of `AC=`.

In my example, the searched values would be for those 4 strings:

```
"D Allocated"
"D Allocated"
"Domain View"
"BE"
```

I could find the position of this last occurrence with

```sql
DATALENGTH(MyTable.[ColumnStrings])-CHARINDEX(REVERSE('=AC'),REVERSE(MyTable.[ColumnStrings]))-1
```

but how to get the substring just after this `=AC` and before the next comma (or the end of the string if we don't find any comma)

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your design; don't store data like this in your RDBMS in the first place. Normalise your design.

Comment: Can you pre-process you data first. It looks like it has a nice regular structure.

Comment: @Lamu It was not my database, I have to do treatment on it :) Of course, it's a weird way to store it.

Comment: @Yes we have there a dynamic structure, but I don't want to make columns with all the occurences, just get one substring, and I guess it's doable in one line (but a long one :)) like SUBSTRING (from the position of this last occurence (I have that in the line I wrote above), until the next comma or end of string)

Comment: @Jonathan if you want to ping someone, you need to spell their display name correctly. :)

Comment: @Larnu, I'm sorry, I read Lamu altough I have a 32 inches screen. Weird no? :)

Comment: Suggest you find a string_splitting function that preserves order, filter for AC rows and grab the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation like yours, a JSON-based approach is a possible option. You need to transform appropriately the input strings into a valid JSON structure - a nested JSON arrays (`AB=iksw0084,AC=Domain View,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased` into `[["AB","iksw0084"],["AC","Domain View"],["AD","pnsas"],["AD","owned"],["AD","increased"]`). Then you need to parse this JSON with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of an array the `key` column holds the 0-based index of each item in the array. The idea is to use this index for the `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` call.

Table:

```
SELECT ColumnStrings
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES 
   ('AB=ikkw0116,AC=BE D Work stations,AC=BE D stations,AC=D Allocated,AD=pnser,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased'),
   ('AB=ikkWA001S1,AC=BE D HD,AC=D Allocated,AD=pnser,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased'),
   ('AB=iksw0084,AC=Domain View,AD=pnsas,AD=owned,AD=increased'),
   ('AB=GHRS05900263,AC=Big stations,AC=GHR,AC=BE,AD=ger,AD=eu,AD=intra')
) v (ColumnStrings)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.StringValue
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT 
      j1.[value], 
      JSON_VALUE([value], '$[0]') AS StringKey, 
      JSON_VALUE([value], '$[1]') AS StringValue,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY JSON_VALUE([value], '$[0]') 
         ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]) DESC
      ) AS RN
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[["', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.ColumnStrings, ',', '"],["'), '=', '","'), '"]]')) j1
) j
WHERE j.StringKey = 'AC' AND j.RN = 1
```

Result:

```
StringValue
-----------
D Allocated
D Allocated
Domain View
BE
```

Comment: Wow Zhorov, that's working so well! Thanks a lot! I replaced Data d by existing table and it's working. I get a column with all the values.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't even think about trying to do this operation on your production database.  Rather, as the comments above suggest, normalize your AD data before bringing it into SQL Server.  In particular, SQL Server has poor/no regex support, which is what you really would need here.  Towards that end, here is a regex pattern you may use to extract the final value for the key `AC`:

```regex
^.*\bAC=([^,]+)
```

### Demo

You may apply this regex to your data, then maybe reimport.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, and your regex is working perfectly, but I would really prefer to extract those data immediately in one request, even if it's not really clean with a lot of substring, patindex, charindex functions, because I don't have an access to the database to create a table or something. I just have an sql request to do and I'm trying to do it without declaring variables because I don't know really well how to do functions etc. Should I learn?